# Converting DB2 date to Oracle date

Tags: oracle, db2, date-formatting

Want to split DB2 date having format 2018-04-12-14.02.16.058110 to Oracle in two different columns with format YYYYMMDD and other with HHMM.

Comment: ....why are you trying to store it as separate fields?  In almost all cases, it's actually easier to query them when it's a combined field (things like "every day at 8PM" usually still have a date filter on the query), although a calendar table may help here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do that. Oracle DATE datatype contains both DATE and TIME components, so - although you might try with different TO_CHAR (or, worse, TO_DATE or TO_TIMESTAMP) functions you find on the Internet, the final result will be the same: values will have both date & time.

Therefore, I'd suggest you to do exactly that: store YYYYMMDD HH**MI** (note MI - minutes, not MM - month).

For example:

```
SQL> select
  2    cast(to_timestamp('2018-04-12-14.02.16.058110',
  3                      'yyyy-mm-dd-hh24.mi.ss,ff6') as date) result
  4  from dual;

RESULT
-------------------
12.04.2018 14:02:16

SQL>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help!! I was trying to create materialized view in Oracle from a DB2 table.